# Airflow Dag Task Failing Global Variable Not Recognized

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the following:

```
def fetch_sf_data():
    response1 = requests.get("https://company.my.salesforce.com/"+ReportID1+"?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv",
                  headers = sf.headers, cookies = {'sid' : sid})
    global salesforce_report
    salesforce_report_raw = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response1.text))
    salesforce_report = salesforce_report_raw[:-5]

def push_to_sql(salesforce_report):
    salesforce_report.to_sql('Daily_Report_SF',engine,if_exists='replace' ,index=False)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fetch_sf_data',
    python_callable=fetch_sf_data,
    dag = dag 
)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_to_sql',
    python_callable=push_to_sql,
    dag=dag
)

t1 >> t2
```

Task 1 runs flawlessly but Task 2 fails and gets the following error code returned:

```
TypeError: push_to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'salesforce_report'
```

I was under the impression that because I declared 'salesforce_report' as a global variable it would pass on through to the next task without a problem. Is that not the case now that I'm using airflow? What should I do in order to make Task 2 not fail?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. This is because in Airflow each task can work on a different machine, hence you should save the result either in **[Xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms)** or S3/GCS or local filesystem. And then read this file in your next task and push to SQL.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Unfortunately, when I do that I get ```Broken DAG: name 'salesforce_report' is not defined```

Comment: Updated the answer