# How can a variable be reused from one task to another task in a DAG?

Tags: airflow

So, I have a couple tasks in a DAG. Let's say I calculate a value and assign it to a variable in the first task. I want to be able to use the variable in the subsequent tasks.
How can I do this?

In a python program, I can just elevate the status of the variable in a function to Global , so that I can use that variable in other functions.

How can I achieve a similar thing with Airflow - use a variable from first task in the subsequent tasks.
I know I can use XCOMS. Is there any other way?

I tried elevating the status of variable to Global in the function called by first task and tried to use it in the subsequent tasks. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in below answer from a similar question, as long as you don't use an XCOM or persistent file, it is impossible to pass variables between tasks.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60495564/19969296

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either write the variable to a file that persists (can be a local file, a relational database, a file in a blob storage) or use XCom (see [this guide](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks) for concrete examples) or Airflow Variables. Is there a reason you don't want to use XCom?

XCom example which is a more common pattern than the Airflow Variable example below:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from pendulum import datetime

@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
)
def write_var():

    @task
    def set_var():
        return "bar"

    @task
    def retrive_var(my_variable):
        print(my_variable)

    retrive_var(set_var())

write_var()
```

The alternative to XCom would be to save the variable as an Airflow variable as shown in this DAG:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.models import Variable

@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
)
def write_var():

    @task
    def set_var():
        Variable.set("foo", "bar")

    @task
    def retrive_var():
        var = Variable.get("foo")
        print(var)

    set_var() >> retrive_var()

write_var()
```